# Lost RAID partition for no clear reason

Tags: raid, sata

We have some machines with a RAID 1 out of two 2TB hard drives.

Now it has been found to the error that the partition was not recognized from OS (Windows in most cases).

In the configuration menu there is the message "set0 invalid raid drive".

The discs are fine. They can be separately mounted in some linux live distributions and S.M.A.R.T. tools shows no errors.

We use an Sli 3512A SATARaid chip with BIOS version 4.3.83. .

Any idea what the cause is or any advise how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

- This problem is happening independent of the OS. (With a seeming preference for Windows OSs)
- The disks are not showing obvious filesystem corruption.
- The disks are not showing obvious physical corruption via SMART.

The major component that is left is the RAID controller itself, specifically it's interaction with the physical hard drives. There could be a problem with timeout mismatches between the hard drives and the controller. When I see disks as larg as 2TB, I am immediately suspicious that they are a consumer grade drive not intended to be used with enterprise disk controllers. Confirm that your disks are designed with the intention of being used in a *hardware* RAID array.

Next, confirm the operation of your RAID card. You mention that the chip is Sli, however Sli to the best of my knowledge does not manufacture and sell RAID cards, but rather makes the chips that other manufactures purchase and use for their own cards. Those manufacturers then provide their own drivers and support. Find the actual manufacturer of your RAID card as a whole, not just the chip manufacturer.

Look for logs files and alerts within the RAID card itself. Seek information from it concerning timeout limits. It's possible that it is holding logs that are not being directly reported to the OS unless the proper drivers have been installed.